# Is there a clever way of getting the sortable target in jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery UI to link a number of lists, and allow items to be dragged and dropped between the different lists.

In the `receive` event, I want to get the list that the item is dropped in.  Is `ui.item.parent()` the correct way to do that, or is there a property of `ui` or `event` which will let me access this directly?

---

```
<ul><li>item 1</li></ul>
<ul><li>item 2</li></ul>
```

---

```
$('ul').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul',
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        var targetList = ui.item.parent();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope, there's no direct property for the new parent (because [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) is easy enough probably), so what you have is correct.  [You can view all the `ui` properties here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/).

If you wanted `.closest()`, the second parent, etc...it's better to leave the UI slim since they're all easy enough to traverse to; this also saves the expense of providing the references directly on the `ui` object.

Comment: Grand, thanks for clearing that up.  Was bothering me slightly, but I think I'll get over it!

Answer (score 11):

Since the `receive` event is called on the receiving list, you can get the new parent by `$(this)`. The source list is accessible via `ui.sender`.

```
$('ul').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul',
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        var sourceList = ui.sender;
        var targetList = $(this);
    }
});
```