# Get the item/object where the element is dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm coding a task panel with three lists and I use sortable to move item between them. But I need to pick up the item where the element is dropped. I know that `ui.item` is the element dropped, but I don't know where I dropped it. Here is my code:

```
$( ".column" ).sortable({
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        /* get the element where ui.item is dropped */
    }
});
```

I know that the element will be any with the `.column` selector, but how to pick!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a clever way of getting the sortable target in jQueryUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420311/is-there-a-clever-way-of-getting-the-sortable-target-in-jqueryui)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very Simple:

```
alert($(this).attr('id')); //this is element where the item was dropped in
```

Comment: This would seem to be correct. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420311/is-there-a-clever-way-of-getting-the-sortable-target-in-jqueryui.

Comment: This is pretty old question, but in my case I was looking for this and I did finally :). Thanks

Comment: actually, $(this) is the element the item was dragged from, not the one it has been dropped in...

Answer (score 7):

EDIT - a way to do that is like this

```
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    receive: function(e, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.closest('ul').attr('id'));

    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Of course if you wan't to get the element next to the dropped element you'd do

```
ui.item.closest('ul')
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/dKaYM/

Comment: If I want to swipe the position than what should I need to add ?