# Formatting Parameters for Ajax POST request to Rails Controller - for jQuery-UI sortable list

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using the jQuery-UI Sortable Connected Lists.  I'm saving the order of the connected lists to a Rails server.

My approach is to grab the list ID, column ID and index position of each list item. I want to then wrap this into an object that can be passed as a parameter back to the Rails Controller to be saved into the database. So ideally i'm looking to format the parameter like this: `Parameters: {"Activity"=>[{id:1,column:2,position:1},{id:2,column:2,position:2} ,...]}`

How do I properly format my parameters to be passed in this Ajax POST request?
Right now, with the approach below, I'm passing on  `Parameters: {"undefined"=>""}`

This is my current jQuery code (Coffeescript) which doesn't work:

```
jQuery ->
  $('[id*="day"]').sortable(
    connectWith: ".day"
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    update: (event, ui) ->
      neworder = new Array()
      $('[id*="day"] > li').each ->
        column = $(this).attr("id")
        index = ui.item.index() + 1
        id = $("#" + column + " li:nth-child(" + index + ") ").attr('id')
        passObject={}
        passObject.id = id
        passObject.column = column
        passObject.index = index
        neworder.push(passObject)
      alert neworder
      $.ajax
        url: "sort"
        type: "POST"
        data: neworder
    ).disableSelection()
```

My apologies because this seems like a really amateur question but I'm just getting started with programming jQuery and Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all your selectors are correct, then you should be able to do this:

```
$.ajax
  url: "sort"
  type: "POST"
  data: { Activity: JSON.stringify(neworder) }
```

---

You can also simplify the rest of your code:

```
update: (event, ui) ->
  neworder = [ ]
  $('[id*="day"] > li').each ->
    # 'this' should be the DOM element so just read off the 'id' attribute,
    # you don't need to waste time building a jQuery object just to get an
    # 'id' attribute.
    column = @id
    index  = ui.item.index() + 1

    # String interpolation to skip the string addition noise. You already
    # have a jQuery object here so there's nothing wrong with using
    # attr('id') here.
    id = $("##{column} li:nth-child(#{index})").attr('id')

    # You don't need 'passObject' here, just use an object literal and push
    # it onto neworder all in one go.
    neworder.push(
      id:     id
      column: column
      index:  index
    )
  $.ajax
    url: "sort"
    type: "POST"
    data: { Activity: JSON.stringify(neworder) }
```

Or even more compact (if you like that sort of thing):

```
update: (event, ui) ->
  neworder = [ ]
  $('[id*="day"] > li').each ->
    index = ui.item.index() + 1
    neworder.push(
      id:     $("##{column} li:nth-child(#{index})").attr('id')
      column: @id
      index:  index
    )
  $.ajax
    url: "sort"
    type: "POST"
    data: { Activity: JSON.stringify(neworder) }
```

Then you can `JSON.parse(params[:Activity])` to unpack it in your controller.

---

After a bit of discussion in the comments, I think your `index` values are wrong. Doing this:

```
index = ui.item.index() + 1
```

will give you the same `index` for each `<li>`. You probably want something more like this:

```
$lis = $('[id*="day"] > li')
$lis.each ->
  index = $lis.index(@)
  #...
```

That should give you the index of the current `<li>` (`@`) within the collection of `<li>`s that you're iterating over. Alternatively, you could use the arguments that [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) passes to the iterator function:

```
$('[id*="day"] > li').each (index, el) ->
  # Just use `index` as-is in here...
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! I'll try this and report back!

Comment: @HungLuu: Sorry about that, I forgot that I have a bunch of local wrappers for dealing with all this stuff by JSONifying and de-JSONifying automatically. Have a look at my changes please.

Comment: I can't figure this out. It seems like using this method gives me a nested hash.    Parameters: {"Activity"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"activity_67", "column"=>"day_48", "index"=>"3"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"activity_67", "column"=>"day_48", "index"=>"3"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"activity_67", "column"=>"day_48", "index"=>"3"}, "3"=>{"id"=>"activity_67", "column"=>"day_49", "index"=>"3"}...} any ideas? @mu is too short

Comment: It would probably help if I updated everything rather than the two place you probably wouldn't look, sorry. If you `data: { Activity: JSON.stringify(neworder) }` in CoffeeScript and then `JSON.parse(params[:Activity])` in your controller it should work.

Comment: You can also look into use [`Content-Type: application/json`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4914925/479863) to get Rails to unpack things for you.

Comment: thank you so much @mu is too short.  your answer definitely works. I'm struggling with my jquery selectors though because I realize that my .each iterator is not going through every li item in a given list.  it's giving me the same activity id and the same index position number. so something is wrong.  working to figure it out and will mark your answer and post my solution hopefully soon! thanks again!

Comment: @HungLuu: I added a little update about `index` and what you probably want it to be.

Comment: Great - thanks so much @muistooshort. I ended up getting it to work after all of your help!  You were exactly right, my index values were wrong. I'll mark this as the answer since it is but will put my final code below in another answer (I made some tweaks to my selectors and how i approached indexing and decided to just use each_with_index on the ruby controller).

Answer (score 0):

This is my jQuery code (in Coffeescript):

```
jQuery ->
  $('[id*="day"]').sortable(
    connectWith: ".day"
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    update: (event, ui) ->
      neworder = new Array()
      $(this).children().each ->
        column = $(this).parent().attr("id").match(/\d+/)[0]
        id = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/)[0]
        neworder.push(
          id: id
          column: column
        )
      alert neworder
      $.ajax
        url: "sort"
        type: "POST"
        data: { Activity: JSON.stringify(neworder) }
    ).disableSelection()
```

How I parse the AJAX call back to the Rails Controller:

```
def sort
    JSON.parse(params[:Activity]).each_with_index do |x, index|
      idx = x["id"]
      positionx = index+1
      column = x["column"]
      activity = Activity.find(idx)
      activity.update_attributes(:position => positionx, :day_id => column)
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

Back in my Model, I order "Activities" association by it's Position.

```
has_many :activities, :order => 'position'
```

Thanks so much for your help @muistooshort