# jQuery AJAX POST to Rails Controller. Error when doing each_with_index (TypeError can't convert Symbol into Integer)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I'm trying to save the position of a jQuery-UI sortable connected list to a Rails backend. I'm having trouble with the Rails Controller action when trying to save the parameters to database.  The error that I am getting is `TypeError (can't convert Symbol into Integer):`

The parameter from the Ajax POST request that I'm sending in looks like this which looks fine:

```
Activity:[{"id":"65","column":"48"},{"id":"65","column":"48"},{"id":"67","column":"48"}]
```

My Rails controller action is this (I'm trying to update an Activity with an id of 'id' and updating the attributes position with 'position' and day_id with 'column':

```
  def sort
    JSON.parse(params[:Activity]).each_with_index do |x, index|
      id = x["id"]
      position = index+1
      column = x["column"]
      Activity.update_all(position = position, day_id = column, id = id)
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

I'm getting this error in  Terminal:

```
    Started POST "/trips/sort" for 10.0.2.2 at 2012-11-04 23:52:30 +0000
Processing by TripsController#sort as */*
  Parameters: {"Activity"=>"[{\"id\":\"66\",\"column\":\"49\"},{\"id\":\"66\",\"column\":\"49\"},{\"id\":\"67\",\"column\":\"49\"}]"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

TypeError (can't convert Symbol into Integer):
```

This is my jQuery AJAX call if helpful:

```
    jQuery ->
  $('[id*="day"]').sortable(
    connectWith: ".day"
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    update: (event, ui) ->
      neworder = new Array()
      $(this).children().each ->
        column = $(this).parent().attr("id").match(/\d+/)[0]
        id = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/)[0]
        neworder.push(
          id: id
          column: column
        )
      alert neworder
      $.ajax
        url: "sort"
        type: "POST"
        data: { Activity: JSON.stringify(neworder) }
    ).disableSelection()
```

I've spent the past few hours on this and just can't figure it out.  I really appreciate the time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to update each activity individually, like so:

```
JSON.parse(params[:Activity]).each_with_index do |x, index|
  id = x["id"]
  position = index+1
  column = x["column"]
  activity = Activity.find(id)
  activity.update_attributes(:position=>position, :column=>column)
end
```

(assuming your JSON parsing works correctly, which I haven't checked)

`Activity.update_all` will update ALL of the activities with the same attributes (eg set all activities to column 5 and position 1), which is not what you want to accomplish here.

Comment: Great this worked! I was confused because I thought the error that I was getting was due to the JSON parsing.  So turns out it was and I was getting errors around using update_all.  I had thought that update_all was the same as update_attributes with the only difference being that update_all updates all of the attributes with a single database call instead of a call for each attribute.  Thank you! @aguynamedloren