# JQuery sortable lists connectWith serialize?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, jquery-ui-sortable

I followed Railscast about sortable lists and it worked perfectly for one sortable list. But when I tried to create two connected sortable lists I've discovered that serialize can store only ids of elements. Is there a way to make serialize store also list's id for each list element id? Or merge list's element parent id into serialize result accordingly?

This answer [jQuery-UI Sortable Connected-Lists save order and association to rails model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204628/jquery-ui-sortable-connected-lists-save-order-and-association-to-rails-model) is quite close to what I am looking, following this I've managed to drag elements between lists and successfully save it to db, but sorting elements withing one list doesn't save properly.

View

```
<% @project.tasks.group_by(&:column).each do |column, tasks| %>
    <ul id='tasks_<%= column %>' data-update-url='<%= sort_project_tasks_url(@project) %>'>
    <% tasks.sort_by! { |t| t.priority }.each do |task| %>
        <li id="task_<%= task.id %>">
        <%= task.name %>| <%= column %> | <b><%= task.priority %></b>
        </li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

The script plain serialization variant I've used.

```
jQuery ->
    $('#tasks_done').sortable
    connectWith: '#tasks_dev'
    update: ->
        $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
```

Script I've got from linked question. It also works fine for dragging elements between lists, but sorting within list won't save properly

```
jQuery ->
    $('#tasks_dev').sortable
    connectWith: '#tasks_done'
    update: (event, ui) ->
        neworder = new Array()
        $(this).children().each ->
            column = $(this).parent().attr('id')
            id = $(this).attr('id').match(/((?!task_).)*$/)[1]
        neworder.push(
            id: id
        column: column
        )
    $.post($(this).data('update-url'), Activity: JSON.stringify(neworder))
```

Corresponding action in controller (without strong params for now), updated for second script variant

```
def sort
     JSON.parse(params[:Activity]).each_with_index do |data, index|
     id = data['id']
     priority = index + 1
     column = data['column']
     column.slice! 'tasks_' # columns ids are tasks_<%= task.column %>
     task = Task.find(id)
     task.update_attributes(priority: priority, column: column)
end
```

So, the main problem is: I can't figure out how to save sort result within one list while keeping track of elements moved between lists. It seems easy to do on server side, but I'm inexperienced with front-end and can't figure out how to form params on client properly.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages. When asking about a problem with your code we need to see the minimum code that duplicates the problem. Without that we're left having to try to imagine your code, when never works well as we can imagine more things than you can describe.

Comment: Sorry for that, updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the solution I came up with. You basically just get list's id, append to it sortable('serialize') result and post it.

tasks.coffee (I'll refactor it with .erb later)

```
jQuery ->
    $('#tasks_done').sortable
    connectWith: '#tasks_dev'
    update: ->
        $.post($(this).data('update-url'), 'column' + '=' + $(this).attr('id') + '&' + $(this).sortable('serialize'))

jQuery ->
    $('#tasks_dev').sortable
    connectWith: '#tasks_done'
    update: ->
        $.post($(this).data('update-url'), 'column' + '=' + $(this).attr('id') + '&' + $(this).sortable('serialize'))
```

tasts_controller.rb

```
def sort
    column = params[:column].delete! 'tasks_'
    params[:task].each_with_index do |id, index|
        Task.where(id: id).update_all(priority: index + 1, column: column)
    end
end
```

Formed params:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7BPn.jpg

(sorry, don't have enough rep to add pictures directly)