# jQueryUI sortable target element ID

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to build a dynamic image-gallery tool and use jquery-ui sortable techniques for drag&drop/sort them.

I want to group them by categories. First I build the lists dynamically and build my connected sortable `<ul>`s. When I drag&drop the images, serialized ids are firing. My AJAX call sends 2 posts to my PHP, for each group new array of `id`s. But my problem is that I need the group-id, where I drop the image to. The id alone isn't enough for my query. For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sortable0, #sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        opacity: 0.6, 
        update: function() {
            var order = $(this).sortable("serialize", {key:"id"});        
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {order: order},                       
                    url: '/backend/ajax/sort_sc_img.php' 
                });   
            }
        });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id ="sortable0" class="connectedSortable">
    <li id="1">
      <img src="image01.jpg">
    </li>
    <li id="2">
      <img src="image02.jpg">
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul id ="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li id="1">
      <img src="image03.jpg">
    </li>
    <li id="2">
      <img src="image04.jpg">
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul id ="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li id="1">
      <img src="image05.jpg">
    </li>
    <li id="2">
      <img src="image06.jpg">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you fix up your javascript code indentation so that it's easier for others to read?

Comment: okay, think i have done what you want

Comment: I am not completely sure what you mean by "group ID" in the question, so I have assumed you mean that you want the parent `<ul>` `id` attribute in my answer. If this is not correct, please edit the question to show which id you need.

Comment: sorry..
the problem: when i have a gallery of images with some different cars and i want to sort them.. 
first i have all cars in one group -> group 0
then i want to order them by color, group 1 are red cars, group 2 are blue cars, etc..
for my sql-query and later sorting i need a group id, and not 0, the source but 1 or 2, the target ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a clever way of getting the sortable target in jQueryUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420311/is-there-a-clever-way-of-getting-the-sortable-target-in-jqueryui)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQueryUI [update function API](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) shows that the function is called back with 2 parameters, `update` and `ui`. The `ui` object has a `sender` property which is:

> The sortable that the item comes from if moving from one sortable to another

So by adding those parameters, you get access to the parent `<ul>`, for example:

```
$("#sortable0, #sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    opacity: 0.6,
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var order = $(this).sortable("serialize", {
            key: "id"
        });

        var group = ui.sender === null ? null : ui.sender[0].id; // get the parent <ul> id
        console.log('group', group, 'order', order); // just log for this demo
    }
});
```

Also, note that the [`serialize`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) only works when the attribute values match a predefined format, which by default is `"setname_number"` so the list items should have `id` like `<li id="foo_1">`. The jQueryUI API allows you to specify a different attribute and regex for the format if you want to not use the default.

**Edit:**

Adding a hook onto the jQueryUI `receive` function allows us to grab the `id` of the receiving target group when an item is dropped.

```
receive: function(event, ui) {
    var group = event.target.id;
    console.log('receiving group', group);

    // do something with the group
}
```

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ex5fhh8z/1/)

Comment: your code work fine, but i need the group-id where the picture was dropped - not where it come from.
i have checked the manual, but on "update" or other events like change i don't find an equivalent to sender, like target..

Comment: and thank you for your hint to serialize correcty, i did this mistake some hours ago

Comment: ah ok, you need to move the AJAX into a `receive` function then. I'll update the demo and answer.

Comment: 2 last thougts:
first, is it possible to join the events for only one ajax call ?
last - when i have dropped the image to the new group, the ajax-requests are already done, i think it's better to reload the whole div ?

Comment: OK, do you want multiple drag&drop's to be grouped into a single AJAX call?

Comment: No.
I actually try to fire only one post and give the orderids from update function to receive function, where i have my ajax - call. i'm a jquery - newbie ;)
actual i have read that i can't pass values from events out of function to an other function ^^

Comment: okay, it works fine, i declare the needed vars outside the functions.. now i can work on my php.. thanks anyway

Comment: I had another quick look and you might be able to just use `var group = event.target.id;` in the `update` function and avoid using the `receive` function