# Jquery sortable + draggable not able to get correct event target id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to build a form builder that can drag div and place one after another and can also place input controls inside it.

It can sort the controls. (refer below : picture) First I drag two Div container and place it inside the master container. After that when I try to place `Div2` inside `Div1` I am not able to get the event target id.

This happens only when two div's are inside the master container. When I drag and drop one div over another from field types I get the correct target id.

[See Fiddle :](http://jsfiddle.net/nayassubramanian/6xvuasgw/166/)

To recreate first drag Div to `mastercontainer(id)` first then try to drag it `childcontainer(id)`

```
   $('.containerHolder').sortable({
        connectWith: '.containerHolder',
        scroll: false,
        revert: true,
        zIndex: 10000,
        helper: "clone",
        placeholder: "control-placeholder",
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            alert(event.target.id); 
          
        }
    });

    $("#fieldTypes li").draggable({
        connectToSortable: ".containerHolder",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
    });

    $(".containerHolder").disableSelection();
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a clever way of getting the sortable target in jQueryUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420311/is-there-a-clever-way-of-getting-the-sortable-target-in-jqueryui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just missed the right event , because `stop()`, will just show, once you drag between containers the target where the drag starts ,

so you can use `recieve()` event to catch where the last change occurred as folow :

```
receive: function(e, ui) {
    alert(e.target.id)
  }
```

see below snippet :

```js
var MasterContainer = {
  "title": "Untitled Form",
  "description": "Description of the form goes here",
  "controls": []
};



$('.container').sortable({
  connectWith: '.container',
  scroll: false,
  zIndex: 10000,
  placeholder: "control-placeholder",
  receive: function(e, ui) {
    alert(e.target.id)
  }
});

$("#container1, #container2").draggable({
  connectToSortable: ".container",
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid",
});


$(".container").disableSelection();
```

```css
.container {
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: #4474FF;
    border: 1px solid #1E44B2;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.container1 {
  display: inline-block;
}


.container .container {
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #45FF41;
    border: 1px solid #04B200;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.item {
    background-color: #FFCB44;
    border: 1px solid #B2840C;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 15px 50px;
}
.item1 {
    background-color: #FFCB44;
    border: 1px solid #B2840C;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    width: 30px;
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
  <div id="container1" class="item1">Div</div>
  <div id="container2" class="item1">List</div>
  <div id="container3" class="item1">Button</div>
</div>

<div id="masterConatiner" class="container">
  master container
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div id="childContainer" class="container">
    ChildContainer

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I just need to get dropped div id.

Comment: In the fiddle, you can see when you drag "Div" to master container it works. It shows master container alert but when we drag Div to master container and then to childcontainer it still show target as mastercontainer.

Comment: In my snippet : it works as expected I think , drag to master shows master then drag to child it shows child , could you explain whats the matter , may be I didn't get the question correctly

Comment: @NayasSubramanian , please see edited http://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/kh9xntup/1/ 
just replaced stop by recieve , in my comprehention now it works !

Comment: @NayasSubramanian it work as posted snippet , if not ,may be problem in broowser ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939022/jquery-ui-sortable-draggable-get-current-index-of-the-dragged-item/65939159#65939159

Comment: any idea on this issue