# jquery ui sortable + draggable get current index of the dragged item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to get the current index of the dragged item. Image attached of the scenario.

First I drag the div to the master container then I have to get the index from master container ie is `0`.

Then I drag the same element to the child container then I need to get the index from the child container ie is `1`.

I have added this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nayassubramanian/6xvuasgw/174/) to show how my code is right now.

```
('.container').sortable({
connectWith: '.container',
 scroll: false,
    zIndex: 10000,
    placeholder: "control-placeholder",
    receive: function(event, ui){
      var id = event.target.id;
     alert(id);
     },});

 $( "#container1, #container2" ).draggable({
  connectToSortable: ".container",
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid",
});


$( ".container" ).disableSelection();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a data attribute in the div to hold the index. Use the on onDrag and onDrop events to renumber the data attribute for each div within the container. Then return the new index number.

Answer (score 1):

Use the update function , then second param of the function (ui) to get the index as : `ui.item.index()`

```
update: function(e, ui) {
    let index = ui.item.index();
    console.log("dragged indx => "+index);
    
  }
```

See below working snippet :

```js
var MasterContainer = {
  "title": "Untitled Form",
  "description": "Description of the form goes here",
  "controls": []
};



$('.container').sortable({
  connectWith: '.container',
  scroll: false,
  zIndex: 10000,
  placeholder: "control-placeholder",
  start: function(e, ui) {
        // creates a temporary attribute on the element with the old index
        // credits to this answer
        $(this).attr('data-previndex', ui.item.index());
    },
  update: function(e, ui) {
    let index = ui.item.index();
    console.log("dragged indx => "+index);
    
  },
  receive: function(e, ui) {
    let id = e.target.id;;
    console.clear();
    console.log("container id => "+ id)
    
  }
});

$("#container1, #container2").draggable({
  connectToSortable: ".container",
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid",
});


$(".container").disableSelection();
```

```css
.container {
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: #4474FF;
    border: 1px solid #1E44B2;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.container1 {
  display: inline-block;
}


.container .container {
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #45FF41;
    border: 1px solid #04B200;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.item {
    background-color: #FFCB44;
    border: 1px solid #B2840C;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 15px 50px;
}
.item1 {
    background-color: #FFCB44;
    border: 1px solid #B2840C;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    width: 30px;
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
  <div id="container1" class="item1">Div</div>
  <div id="container2" class="item1">List</div>
  <div id="container3" class="item1">Button</div>
</div>

<div id="masterConatiner" class="container">
  master container
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div id="childContainer" class="container">
    ChildContainer

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: could you check the answer , hope I've understand your problem !

Comment: with this we just get the index of the container isn't. this doesn't solve my problem. Even the child container is dynamically created. From the fiddle I created one can drag multiple Div to any container and from any container. I want to get the index of  each div in the present container.

Comment: @NayasSubramanian ah okey , I was thinking you want the id of container , rather then dragged item , see updated asnwer

Comment: always getting -1 as the index.

Comment: could you check here this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/u7dbny2t/12/)

Comment: @NayasSubramanian , Same issue ? for me no -1 value !

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/tsxz319r/44/

**JavaScript**

```
var MasterContainer = {
  "title": "Untitled Form",
  "description": "Description of the form goes here",
  "controls": []
};

$('.container').sortable({
  connectWith: '.container',
  scroll: false,
  zIndex: 10000,
  placeholder: "control-placeholder",
  receive: function(event, ui) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    console.log("ID: " + id + ", Index: " + ui.helper.data("start-index"));
  },
});

$("#container1, #container2").draggable({
  connectToSortable: ".container",
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid",
  create: function(e, ui) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("item1")) {
      $(this).each(function(i, el) {
        $(el).data("start-index", i);
      });
    }
  },
  start: function(e, ui) {
    ui.helper.attr("data-start-index", $(this).index());
  }
});

$(".container").disableSelection();
```

When you use `clone` for the draggable, it will not clone `data` or `events` applied to it. So if we add an Attribute that can store the data, this will carry across with the drag.

When I review the structure, it seems a bit confused. I would stick to using all unique IDs or remove the IDs where you can and make better use if Classes.

Comment: This is what I am getting 
" ID: masterConatiner, Index: 0"
"ID: childContainer, Index: 0"
"ID: masterConatiner, Index: 0"
"ID: masterConatiner, Index: 0"

Comment: @NayasSubramanian that sounds correct for the first item, "Div", in the list. You should get `1` for the second item, "List": ID: `masterConatiner, Index: 0` and `ID: masterConatiner, Index: 1`

Comment: I am getting 0 for the second item too.

Comment: @NayasSubramanian this would suggest an issue in indexing the elements. Please Edit your post and provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example